# How to add an end tag on a List when using XML Serialization in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to add an end tag when I try to serialize an xml file, and it's not working just right.  Here is the class I am using

```
private List<RTACModuleDeviceConnectionSettingPagesSettingPageRowSetting> rowField;

    /// <remarks/>
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Setting", typeof(RTACModuleDeviceConnectionSettingPagesSettingPageRowSetting), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = false)]
    public List<RTACModuleDeviceConnectionSettingPagesSettingPageRowSetting> Row
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rowField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rowField = value;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to write the XML:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;
        //settings.CloseOutput = true;
        //settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(deserializedDevice.GetType());

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, deserializedDevice, ns);

        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        File.WriteAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
```

I am expecting to get this written out:

```
        <Row>
        <Setting enabled="false">
          <Column>Setting</Column>
          <Value>Network Connection Type</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Value</Column>
          <Value>Telnet</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Comment</Column>
          <Value />
        </Setting>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Setting enabled="false">
          <Column>Setting</Column>
          <Value>Local Port Number</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Value</Column>
          <Value>5206</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Comment</Column>
          <Value />
        </Setting>
      </Row>
```

Instead I am missing my multiple end tags on Row:

```
        <Row>
        <Setting
          enabled="false">
          <Column>Setting</Column>
          <Value>Network Connection Type</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Value</Column>
          <Value>Telnet</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Comment</Column>
          <Value />
        </Setting>
        <Setting
          enabled="false">
          <Column>Setting</Column>
          <Value>Local Port Number</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Value</Column>
          <Value>5315</Value>
        </Setting>
        <Setting>
          <Column>Comment</Column>
          <Value />
        </Setting>
      </Row>
```

Comment: What is the data you are using and how is it constructed in memory? It looks from the Xml like you are serializing one array with 6 elements in - in much case it will serialize one element for the array (Row) and 6 for the elements of the array (Settings).

Comment: I am reading in a xml file (xmlReader) without modifying it, serialize it and trying to write it back out to an xml.  The Row list should have 3 elements(Settings) underneath it, then it should start a new row tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change the class to 2 different XMLElementAttributes to get it to work, Richard Matheson was very close. Setting and Row had to be separated.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Row", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public RTACModuleDeviceConnectionSettingPagesSettingPage[] Row
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rowField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rowField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Setting", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public List<RTACModuleDeviceConnectionSettingPagesSettingPageRowSetting> Setting
    {
        get
        {
            return this.settingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.settingField = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the serialization code, you need to work on the structure of your classes if you want serialization to work.

If you want it to write out 3 settings per row, then you need to construct the classes something like the following:

```
class Row
{
    [XmlElement("Setting")] Setting[] Settings { get; set; } //Use an array of 3 elements here. A list should work as well. 
}

class Setting
{
    [XmlElement] public string Column { get; set; }
    [XmlElement] public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you serialize out a collection such as List... you will get a set of rows with 3 elements.

If you don't want to modify your structures to work like this, then you'll have to write classes to create the xml manually, which may or may not be easier.

Also, you might want to choose a shorter, easier to read name than `RTACModuleDeviceConnectionSettingPagesSettingPageRowSetting`. It's difficult to read even in the small code sample you've got there.